# How to get redirect URL with SFSafariVieController in objective c?

Tags: ios

I am using SFSafariViewController first time, Help me to know that How to get redirect URL with SFSafariVieController in objective c?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code hope it will helpful for you:**

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.google.searchAPIs.detail")
        myActivity.title = "Cupertino" // 2
        myActivity.eligibleForSearch = true // 4
        myActivity.keywords = Set(arrayLiteral: "Cupertino", "Silcon Valley", "California", "San Jose", "San Francisco", "Apple Inc", "Mothership") // 5
        self.userActivity = myActivity // 6
        myActivity.eligibleForHandoff = false // 7
        myActivity.becomeCurrent() // 8



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func didPressButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(URL:NSURL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupertino,_California")!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true) // Set to false if not interested in using reader
        safariVC.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController) {

        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi prince, I am using fitbit login-api, I need to get url after login.
I am using code in objective c. Kindly help me with objective c

Comment: check also this link hope this might helps you: https://omarmetwally.quora.com/Integrating-the-Fitbit-API-in-iOS-apps